# Why does this Shaker-Sort implementation take so long to run?

Tags: c

I want to find the execution time for a sorting algorithm.
I wrote before the algorithm code

```
start_time = clock();
```

And after the algorithm

```
end_time = clock;
time = (double)(end_time - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

The problem is that I tried it on an array with 5 elements to see how it works and I got the time 4201.43600 seconds, which isn't possible for this nr. of elements.

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong?
The code for the function is

```
void ShakerSort(int A[], int n, int (*compare)(int a, int b), int* compare_nr, int* swap_nr, double* time)
{
    clock_t start_time, end_time;
    int i, swapped, begin, end;
    *compare_nr = 0;
    *swap_nr = 0;
    swapped = 1;
    begin = -1;
    end = n-1;
    start_time = clock();
    while (swapped) {
        swapped  = 0;
        begin += 1;
        for (i = begin; i < end; i++) {
            *compare_nr +=1;
            if ((*compare)(A[i], A[i+1])) {
                swap(&A[i], &A[i+1]);
                swapped = 1;
                *swap_nr += 1;
            }
        }
        if (!swapped) break;
        swapped = 0;
        end -= 1;
        for (i = end; i > begin-1; i--) {
            *compare_nr +=1;
            if ((*compare)(A[i], A[i+1])) {
                swap(&A[i], &A[i+1]);
                swapped = 1;
                *swap_nr += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    end_time = clock();
    *time = (double)(end_time - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

A is the array with elements

n is the nr. of elements

(*compare) is the way of comparing, ascending or descending

compare_nr is the nr. of comparisons of elements

swap_nr is the nr. of swaps that were made

time is the time of execution of the function

Comment: Missing `()` in your second snippet. Please post your real code.

Comment: This was the problem, but the compiler didn't show any errors. I checked more than 10 times and I anyway I missed it. Thank you

Comment: Make sure you turn on all warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror` at minimum for gcc and clang).

Comment: @Tom Which compiler do you use? No standard-compliant C compiler should automatically convert function pointers (clock) to integers (end_time).

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks